# c# Dictionary copy a value not a reference

Tags: c#, dictionary

We all know that in this situation:

```
String[] table= new String[3];
table[0] = "x"
table[1] = "x"
table[2] = "x"
Dictionary<string, String[]> dict = new Dictionary<string, String[]>();
dict.Add("sth",table);
table[0] = "y"
table[1] = "y"
table[2] = "y"
dict.Add("sth2",table);
```

I will get different keys but the same value `yyy` because here `dict.Add()` we give a reference. Is there a way to give not a reference but a values, f.e. to get:

```
<"sth",{x,x,x}>
<"sth",{y,y,y}>
```

Answer (score 2):

Cloning the Array should work, as `string` is supposed to be immutable.

```
String[] table = new String[3];

table[0] = "x"
table[1] = "x"
table[2] = "x"

Dictionary<string, String[]> dict = new Dictionary<string, String[]>();

dict.Add("sth", (string[])table.Clone());

table[0] = "y"
table[1] = "y"
table[2] = "y"

dict.Add("sth2", (string[])table.Clone());
```

Answer (score 1):

For your specific example you probably need to copy array on add.

```
dict.Add("sth",table.ToArray());
```

If you need Immutability and performance (because copying is not really efficient method) - look at [Immutable Collections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn769092(v=vs.111).aspx), specifically at [ImmutableList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn467185(v=vs.111).aspx)